# Make bootstrap navbar fixed in horizonatal scroll

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar that needs to be kept fixed in horizontal scroll, it already kept fixed for normal(vertical) scrolling, but during horizontal scroll, it gets scrolled away

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, as per web development standards, you shouldn't have horizontal scrolls on your webpages as this is considered as bad practice.

But still for any specific case you want to do it then you can use style `position:fixed` to do it.

HTML:

```
<nav class="fixedbar">
    ...
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.fixedbar {
     position: fixed;
}
```

Or using inline CSS:

HTML:

```
<nav style="position: fixed">
    ...
</nav>
```